# Sending .jpg from Android to c++ using sockets

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, sockets

I am currently working on a project using a smartphone and a Raspberry Pi.
I have one problem, which is the fact that i cannot send correctly the .jpg from the phone.
I have successfully sent the size of the photo which is the length of the byte array that should be sent after.
Can anyone help me?

Part of Client (Android Studio - Java)

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.2.122",1234);
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/poza/cam_image.jpg");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStream is=fis;
byte[] message=IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
String zxc;
zxc = Integer.toString(message.length);
dOut.writeBytes(zxc);
dOut.write(message);
```

Part of Server (QT Creator - C++)

```
socket->waitForBytesWriten();
socket->waitForReadyRead(100);
char request[6];
socket->read(request,6);
request[6]=NULL;
int bs; 
bs=atoi(request); //bs is the length which has the correct value
```

I have also tried to send the byte array in chunks, but I probably hadn't written it correctly as it didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have successfully managed to send it, thank you for all your help.

Part of Client(GOOD)

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.2.122",1234);
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/poza/cam_image.jpg");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStream is=fis;
byte[] message=IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
int leng = message.length;
byte [] length = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(message.length).array(); //int to bytes
System.out.println(message.length);
byte [] newLen = new byte[4]; //little endian, big endian stuff
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    System.out.println(length[i]); //original bytes
    newLen[3-i]=length[i]; //reversing order
}
dOut.write(newLen); //sending the size of image
dOut.flush();
dOut.write(message);//send image
```

Part of Server (GOOD)

```
QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
socket->waitForConnected();
qDebug()<<"connected";
char *sockData = new char[92160000]; //max bytes size for photo
int size = 0; //photo size
int bytes = 0; //bytes read at a time

qDebug()<<"waiting for bytes";
socket->waitForReadyRead();
socket->read((char*)&size,sizeof(int)); //reading the size of the photo
qDebug()<<"the size is just " <<size;
for(int i=0;i<size;i+=bytes){ //reading the rest of bytes
    socket->waitForReadyRead();
    bytes = socket->read(sockData+i,size-i);
    if(bytes==-1){
        printf("error");
        break;
    }
}
qDebug()<<"success in reading the image";
std::vector<char> data(sockData,sockData+size);
if(data.size()==0){
    qDebug()<<"errorrrrr";
    return;
}
Mat temporary = cv::imdecode(data,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv::imshow("sdfsd",temporary);
cv::waitKey(1000);
delete sockData;//memory deallocation
```

Comment: In what way didn't it work?  Any errors?  Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: No code error, runtime problems. I have been trying to solve this for some days

Comment: You are not even reading the image bytes on the receiving side. So where should we comment on?

Comment: i said these are only parts

Answer (score 0):

After converting the image data to a byte array, why are you sending the array's `length` as a `string`?  A `string` is variable-length, but you are not telling the receiver what the string length actually is, either by sending the actual string length before sending the string, or by placing a unique terminator after the string.  As such, the receiver has no way to know reliably where the length string actually ends and the image data begins.  Your receiver is just blindly reading 6 bytes (why 6? That will only work for images that are between 100000-999999 bytes in size), but is then replacing the **7th** byte with a null terminator (thus trashing memory, as only space for 6 bytes was allocated), before then reading the actual image bytes.

You should be sending the image byte count as raw binary data, not as a variable-length `string`.  Use `dOut.writeInt(message.length)` to send the array `length` as a 4-byte integer (in network byte order).

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.2.122",1234);
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/poza/cam_image.jpg");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] message = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dOut.writeInt(message.length);
dOut.write(message);
```

Then the receiver can read the first 4 bytes (swapping the bytes to host order if needed), and then interpret those bytes as an integer that specifies how many image bytes to read:

```
socket->waitForBytesWriten();
socket->waitForReadyRead(100);
int32_t bs;  // <-- be sure to use a 4-byte data type
socket->read((char*)&bs, 4);
bs = ntohl(bs);
//bs is the image length to read
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried the same method for sending the length, but i didn't use int32_t, i used int and the server received things like \x and the size were hexadecimal, so i started messing things up until i got the correct value(i was also logging the value in android studio), thank you again for solving this problem.

Comment: `int` is not 4 bytes in size on all platforms.  If it is on your system, fine.  Otherwise, use a fixed-width data type like `int32_t`, which is [defined in `<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) in C and [in `<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) in C++.